# How to make WP in two languages (e.g. English & Bengali) without plugins

Tags: multi-language

I want to make a WordPress website in 2 languages (e.g. English & Bengali) without plugins. Currently my site is plain html with 2 folders. English pages in one folder and Bengali pages in another folder. How do I do it on WordPress without plugin? How to do it theme page/post?

Comment: You're almost certainly going to need one or more plugins to achieve this.

Comment: you use two different sites, or a multisite setup

Answer (score 3):

A way my agency has chosen to implement it in the past is through [subdomains](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-4080). We created the entirety of our English site as you would normally in WordPress on mydomain.com, used the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to clone the site to spanish.mydomain.com, and then changed all the text on the new site.

And as @MarkKaplun recommends, a [multisite](https://wpmudev.com/blog/multilingual-wordpress-site-multisite/) setup would be appropriate here as well, though slightly more complex. It lets you keep the same WordPress core for both sites, but different content.

**An** option is to use a plugin like [WPML](https://wpml.org) (which is generally considered the best plugin to use if you ended up wanting to go that route). However, there are issues as pointed out by @MarkKaplun such as the integration with other plugins and WPML assuming all content should be the same.

Comment: wpml and other have major flow, they assume content should be the same which in many settings it should not. wpml is good in tracking that you have translated everything, but again translating is rarely the right thing to do. (and lets not even talk about complications with using other code which needs to integrate with those plugins, search problem and other things that I might have forgotten about)

Comment: @MarkKaplun Excellent points I hadn't considered, thank you for that. I updated my answer to reflect this. Maybe should've just let you write the answer with how much I'm quoting you here :)

Comment: Thank you @YourManDan for your quick response. I'm against using translation plugins. I've already tried a few plugins, but they don't work well in Bengali. I want my site to use the text that I myself have translated. It's simple for me to think about sub-domains. Once more, many thanks.

Comment: @GopalBhattacharjee WPML in particular does let you enter in your own translation text, but following Mark's advice I would agree that it isn't the best option in this use case. Happy coding!